# Backbone Layoutmanager delegateEvents on subview not working

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-layout-manager

What I have is the following:

```
Views.Parent = Backbone.View.extend( {
    template: "parent",
    initialize: function( ) {
        this.render( );
    },
    beforeRender: function( ) {
        this.setView( ".foo", new Views.Child( {
            model: this.model
        } );
    },
    afterRender: function( ) {
        this.$el.html( Handlebars.compile( this.$el.html( ) ).call( this, this.model.attributes ) );
        var foo = this.getView( ".foo" );
        foo.delegateEvents( ); 
    }
} );

Views.Child = Backbone.View.extend( {
    template: "child",
    events: {
        "click input": "inputClick"
    },
    initialize: function( ) {
        this.listenTo( this.model, "change", this.render );
    },
    inputClick: function( ) {
        console.info( "Input Clicked" );
    }, 
    afterRender: function( ) {
        this.$el.html( Handlebars.compile( this.$el.html( ) ).call( this, this.model.attributes ) );
        var foo = this.getView( ".foo" );
        foo.delegateEvents( ); 
    }
} );
```

The events in `Views.Child` aren't firing. The view is definitely found and foo.events returns the correct events. I've tried multiple ways of inserting my sub-view, delegateEvents just isn't doing it.

Has anybody else run in to this and can offer any insight?

I should mention I'm using both the events property and this.listenTo in the sub-view. None of them are being fired.

Edit: The parent is being added to another view as such:
`this.$el.append( parentView.$el );`

Where `parentView` is an instantiated object of `Views.Parent`.

Comment: What does Views.Child look like?

Comment: I updated the post. It's a simplified version of the code I'm actually running for the sake of clarity.

Comment: `this.listenTo(model, "change", this.render);` `"model"` should not be string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling `this.$el.html` in `afterRender`, you are overwriting the view current HTML (and every bound events/child view). As so, you're removing the child view you set in `beforeRender`.

That's why you got no event firing up.

I'd like to provide more insight as to how you should organize your code... But I can't understand what you're trying to do in `afterRender`, this make no sense at all. Compile all your template code inside the [`fetch`](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki/Configuration#fetchpath) and [`render`](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki/Configuration#rendertemplate-context) configurations options, not in `afterRender`.

A quick note:
`beforeRender`: where you set child views
`afterRender`: where you bind events or startup jQuery plugins, etc. You should not be touching the DOM here.

Comment: You nailed it, I was using layoutmanager incorrectly. I was able to refactor handlebars to LayoutManager.fetch and use serialize to pass the context. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Been a pleasure, good luck. BTW, feel free to hop in #backbone-boilerplate IRC channel if you want to discuss more of concepts.